# kickstart installation is not starting on redhat linux (AWS)

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, kickstart

I want to make a kickstart installation of centos 7 however, the VM starts but route me to a manual textuel installation (which succeeds).

I run this commad to start the installation

```
virt-install --name centos7 --ram 2500 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/centos7.qcow2,size=8 --vcpus 1 --os-type linux --network bridge=virbr0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --location 'http://mirror.i3d.net/pub/centos/7/os/x86_64/' --initrd-inject=anaconda-ks.cfg  --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial file:./anaconda-ks.cfg'
```

And here is the content of my anaconda-ks.cfg

Could you help please

```
#version=DEVEL
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Install, not upgrade
install
url --url http://mirror.rackspace.com/CentOS/7/os/x86_64/
# Use graphical install
no graphical
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
ignoredisk --only-use=vda
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=fr-oss --xlayouts='fr (oss)'
# System language
lang fr_FR.UTF-8

# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --onboot=off --ipv6=auto --no-activate
network  --hostname=localhost.localdomain

# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $6$ZHmnThmzueju.0jF$QGe7zbGuzSqKnSUW9eW7W7NIUP6T/Benhwrm4XxNDwbrPqGz5s5205MCvvGfJoRCXkQCEBIWvEvw.Q1BIBUax1
# System services
services --enabled="chronyd"
# System timezone
timezone Europe/Paris --isUtc
user --groups=wheel --name=niort --password=$6$QarIgmCGEUGB0ngM$ooa53.j3lObWuUr65L/JG53T29TpeLG5jRY7wOQsdQH5uVaeXrXytR/yhCFea9Fa2swxRS3pAp2iLhf/fDW3a/ --iscrypted --gecos="niort"
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=vda
autopart --type=lvm
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel

%packages
@^minimal
@core
chrony
kexec-tools

%end

%addon com_redhat_kdump --enable --reserve-mb='auto'

%end

%anaconda
pwpolicy root --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
pwpolicy user --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --emptyok
pwpolicy luks --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
%end
```

Comment: What was the error that you received?

Comment: no error, but the automatic installation does not start!!

Comment: If the installation did not start, the reason why will be visible on the screen. You can also switch terminals to get more detailed information from the logs.